# My div Element Is Gone After page refresh Help me

Tags: javascript

```
<script>

function create()

{

    var div = document.createElement('div');

    div.textContent = document.getElementById('text').value;

    div.setAttribute('class', 'note');

    document.body.appendChild(div);

    div.style.background="yellow";

    div.style.Width="300px";

    div.style.height="100px";

    if(document.getElementById('text').value=="")

    {
        div.parentNode.removeChild(div);

        alert("Plz Put Some text");
    }
}

</script>

<body>

<input type="button" onclick="create()" value="create"/>

<input type="text" id="text" />

</body>
```

Comment: Every time you load the page, you will get a fresh copy. Changes you make to the DOM will not be saved if you refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Problem could be in this line.

```
<input type="text" id="text" />
```

Because you have checked this condition

```
if(document.getElementById('text').value=="")
```

But you did not give any value to the id="text".

try this .     `<input type="text" id="text" value="user" />`